# Switch to app window only on active desktop on macOS Sierra

Tags: macos, mac, multiple-monitors, macos-sierra

I have two external monitors connected to my mac, each of which is assigned a separate desktop. Usually I have multiple windows of same application (e.g. IntelliJ) on each desktop/monitor. For e.g.

- Desktop1 - FireFox, IntelliJ Window1
- Desktop2 - ITerm, IntelliJ Window2

Now if Desktop1 has FireFox window at top currently, and Desktop 2 has ITerm on top currently, when I click on IntelliJ icon in dock on Desktop2, I want IntelliJ Window2 to show up on top only in Desktop 2. But currently it brings IntelliJ Window1 on Desktop 1 on top too which is not what I want. I want to keep FireFox on Desktop 1 as it is.

My settings:

- MC - Displays have separate spaces : Checked
- MC - When switching to an application, switch to a space...: Checked
- Dock is auto hide and show.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Note: None of the apps are full screen.

Comment: Right now the Mac is doing what it's supposed to - bringing the requested app to the front; which includes all windows of that app. I think the only way to achieve this would be if you can run 2 instances of InteliJ as separate processes [but if/how is beyond my knowledge; some apps have a flag you can set to enable this, some you can launch by applescript/shellscript, others you have to literally duplicate the application & launch each separately]

Comment: IntelliJ was just an example. It could be other apps too.

Comment: That doesn't actually change the essence of my response.

Comment: Please don't cross-post on different SE sites - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/304297/switch-to-app-window-only-on-active-desktop-on-macos-sierra Pick one & stick to it. You can flag an admin to migrate if you need.